# Extracting Ring/Sector area from array representing an image

Tags: matlab

I am trying to extract features from an array representation of an image in MATLAB. 
The features have a shape of a circle (ring) and a sector. This is shown in the image below. I have spent quite some time looking for a built-in function which does this. I have managed to do the ring extraction using an ugly looking loop but no idea where to start on the sector part. Any ideas how to implement this or even better a built-in function in MATLAB would be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty easy, with no for loops needed, see for example in case your image is `im`:

```
[x y]=meshgrid(1:size(im,1));

f =@(x0,y0,r_max,r_min,theta1,theta2) ...
                 (x-x0).^2+(y-y0).^2<=r_max^2 & ...
                 (x-x0).^2+(y-y0).^2>=r_min^2 & ...
                  atan2(y-y0,x-x0)>=theta1 & ...
                  atan2(y-y0,x-x0)<=theta2;
```

`f` is a one liner anonymous function that accepts all needed parameters and gives a mask of the sector needed. For a ring you can set theta to be -pi to pi, or just delete the `atan` part from `f`. For example

```
r_max=40;
r_min=10;
x0=round(size(im,1)/2); %image center
y0=round(size(im,1)/2); %image center
theta1=deg2rad(10);
theta2=deg2rad(70);

imagesc(f(x0,y0,r_max,r_min,theta1,theta2))
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
axis square
```

[image]