# Matlab edge expansion vectorization

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vectorization

I have the following matlab code in a project of mine. `image_working` at this point is a logical image, the result of edge detection. The below loop expands each white point to be essentially a cross with width `width` (this is so a later call to `imfill()` will find more closed regions. The four if statements check that each point is within the original bounds.

```
[edge_row, edge_col] = find(image_working);
for width = 1:width_edge_widen
    for i = 1:length(edge_row)
        if (edge_row(i) + width <= m)
            image_working(edge_row(i) + width, edge_col(i)) = 1;
        end
        if (edge_row(i) - width >= 1)
            image_working(edge_row(i) - width, edge_col(i)) = 1;
        end
        if (edge_col(i) + width <= n)
            image_working(edge_row(i), edge_col(i) + width) = 1;
        end
        if (edge_col(i) - width >= 1)
            image_working(edge_row(i), edge_col(i) - width) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

I suspect there's a good way to vectorize it and avoid the top-level loop, but I'm at a loss as to how to go about it. Simply indexing (like `image_working(edge_row, edge_col)`) doesn't work, since this will give give a rectangular region rather than the individual points. Linear indexing (calling `inds = find(image_working)`) is undesirable because it's difficult to do both vertical and horizontal shifts, although there may well be a vectorizable transform on the indices that I haven't thought of. Any advice?

Comment: You just want to propagate the binary pixels?  What about smearing the whole image, something like: imout = image_working; for width = 1:width_edge_widen; imout = imout | image_working(:,[ones(1,width), 1:end-width]) | image_working(:, [width+1:end, ones(1,width)]) | image_working([ones(1,width), 1:end-width],:) | image_working([width+1:end, ones(1,width)],:); end .  Depending on the sparsity of the image, this is a lot of ops, but it's vectorized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a "vectorized" solution will not neseserally be the fastest here, this depends in how sparse your binary image is. Second, here are a few solutions that will be faster than your code:

First create a random binary image

```
im0=rand(2000)>0.999; % this means sparsity (density) ~ 1e-3
```

**Solution 1** - for loop  (for a cross of width 1, but you can change it as needed):

```
im=im0;
sd=size(im);
width=1;
[x y]=find(im((1+width):sd(1)-(width+1), (1+width):sd(2)-(width+1)));
x=x+width; y=y+width;
for n=1:numel(y)
    im(x(n)-width:x(n)+width,y(n))=1;
    im(x(n),y(n)-width:y(n)+width)=1;
end
```

**Solution 2** - vectorized and one line (for a cross of width 1):

```
im=conv2(single(im0),[0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0],'same')>0;
```

**Solution 3** - vectorized logical indexing  (for a cross of width 1)

```
im =( im0(2:end-1,2:end-1) |  im0(1:end-2,2:end-1) |...
      im0(2:end-1,1:end-2) |  im0(3:end  ,2:end-1) |...
      im0(2:end-1,3:end));

im =[zeros(1,size(im,2)); im; zeros(1,size(im,2))];
im= [zeros(size(im0,1),1) im zeros(size(im,1),1)];
```

You'll see that for sparse images the for loop will be faster than the other methods.

```
Solution 1: Elapsed time is 0.028668 seconds.
Solution 2: Elapsed time is 0.041758 seconds.
Solution 3: Elapsed time is 0.120594 seconds.
```

For less sparse images say (~1%) you can use the vectorized solution (Solution 2), as the for loop will very quickly become less efficient but I would check performance on your data before deciding.

---

**Bonus edit**, for fun I vectorized the cross filter in solution 2 to have arbitrary width as follows:

```
f=@(width) circshift(vander([1 zeros(1,2*width)]),[width -width]);
```

so `im=conv2(single(im0),f(1),'same')>0;` is equivalent to what is written in Solution 2, but now you can use any `f(width_size)` you want.

Comment: Nice answer and nice comparison.

Comment: Thanks! My images are somewhere between 5 and 20% white (the result of edge detection on what's essentially an image with a bunch of circles), so your vectorized solution looks like it's the best. The results from testing them all (on a 528 x 710 image)
**My old method: 3.766 seconds, Solution 1 (better loop): 0.607 seconds, Solution 2 (vectorized): 0.014 seconds.** That's a pretty stark difference!

Comment: Another thing that suggests that method is now I can use arbitrary shapes to expand the image -- not just a cross. This may well be useful for what I'm doing

Comment: you are absolutely right, look into `fspecial` for some traditional filters that matlab has, or search in SO for less traditional binary mask shapes (for instance this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462086/extracting-ring-sector-area-from-array-representing-an-image/23464422#23464422 )