# Fill area between concentric circles in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have pairs of concentric circles. I want to fill area btween these concentric circles in matlab. I am trying "fill" function...but it is filling the outre circle completely.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? What does this image look like? Show us what you have done so far!  If not, then this post will close very quickly.  My suggestion would be to fill the entire outer circle, then do a logical `NOT` operation with the area of the inner circle.

Comment: Duplicate ? (cant decide yet) see this for a solution without fill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462086/extracting-ring-sector-area-from-array-representing-an-image/23464422#23464422

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way using `patch`:

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
x0=1; y0=3;              % circles center
rin = 0.4; rout = 0.6;   % radii sizes
patch([x0+rout*cos(t),x0+rin*cos(t)],[y0+rout*sin(t),y0+rin*sin(t)],'r','linestyle','none');
```

[image]

Comment: Wow... didn't know `patch` existed.  Very nice!